# Set an image to body section only using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a site which is divided into header, footer and body. So I want to put a background image to body section only. How can I do it? I tried it with table tag but i was not able to finish it. I have a separate file for .css. I tried to use background property of table tag like this:

```
<table background="../images/logo.jpg">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2 align="center">About Us</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I also tried to over ride the style.css file's table property by setting an inline css by this:

```
<table STYLE="background-image:"../images/logo.jpg"">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <h2 align="center">About Us</h2>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is not showing the desired result. In both the cases I can't see the image.

Comment: Your first example should work. I'd suggest you double-check to see if your image is properly being referenced. Or if the top portion of the image is white and the table is not high enough, it's getting cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now u are putting a background image to your table but your question is pointing out to have it in the background of the webpage?

In any case. U have here an example of a background image:

[JSFIDDLE example of table background **COLOR**](http://jsfiddle.net/LeQNQ/)

[JSFIDDLE example of table background **IMAGE**](http://jsfiddle.net/83sR6/)

```
P.s.: Vote up if my anwswer helped! ^^
```

Comment: ok, than show me this with 2 tables and i only want a background image on one table only and the color on the second.

Comment: Is this what u ment?

[2 tables, one color, second image](http://jsfiddle.net/8WBw6/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<body background="../images/logo.jpg">
```

or you can use CSS property background-image

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/logo.jpg');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I would suggest you to place the code below inside your html document.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url('../images/logo.jpg');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it is positioned at the top left but i want it only in the body section.

Comment: that is just positioning you can use,

center center

Comment: here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp you can find more accurate description for background-position